# Foundation Reveal Modal not closing with React 15.3.2

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

My modal works properly, i.e. opens and closes **first time** perfectly, however, it does not open **again**. I see the following error in console -

1. > Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node':
   >   The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
2. > Uncaught (in promise) Error: Attempted to update component 'ErrorModal' that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount).

Do I need to destroy my modal every time I close?

## ErrorModal.jsx

```js
var React = require('react');

var ErrorModal = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    var modal = new Foundation.Reveal($('#error-modal'));
    modal.open();
  },
  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className='reveal tiny text-center' id='error-modal' data-reveal="">
        <h4>Some title</h4>
        <p>Our Error msg</p>
        <p>
          <button className ='button hollow' data-close="">
            Okay
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );

  }
});

module.exports = ErrorModal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution using react-dom to let react take care of updating the dom instead of foundation

```
/* global $, Foundation */
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

class ErrorModal extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    const modalContent = (
      <div id='error-modal'
        className='reveal tiny text-center'
        data-reveal=''>
        <h4>Some title</h4>
        <p>our error message</p>
        <p>
          <button className='button hollow' data-close=''>
            Okay
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    )
    const modalElement = $(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(modalContent))
    $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).html(modalElement)

    const modal = new Foundation.Reveal($('#error-modal'))
    modal.open()
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div />
    )
  }
}

export default ErrorModal
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation now with reveal in ZF==6.2.1

Foundation Reveal Modal after run `modal.open();`  foundation change DOM and move modal to end of body - append new overlay. 
Component leave react mounted node  - it's problem